# Подскажите, где я не прав, не могу сделать, чтобы вводило через командную строку

Tags: java

```
class project {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers");  // выводиться в любом случае, для красоты
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //тут по идеи должно вводиться значение, но не работает
        int m = n%360/60;  // подсчет введенного из консоля числа операция 1
        int s = n%360%60;  // подсчет введенного из консоля числа операция 2
        System.out.println(m + "test " + s + "text"); //вывод по формулам и
    }
}
```

Надо ввести переменную, но пишет

> Exception in thread "main" ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at testone.main(testone.java:4)

Что я делаю не так объясните плизз...

Comment: Компилятор подсказывает Вам, что использование args[0] может привести к не обрабатываемому исключению ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (выход индекса за границы массива). Соответственно, такая ситуация возникнет, если Вы не передали аргументы при запуске. Добавьте обработку исключения, и всё должно заработать.

Comment: А как вводить просто переменную или как добавить исключения? Хотелось бы просто ввести значение n и просто чтобы посчитало по формулам, я просто noob, подскажите, хочу понять

Comment: Массив args содержит параметры программы, переданные через командную строку. Очевидно, вы никакие параметры не передали.

Comment: Странно, я запускаю через подпад++ и жду чтобы ввести параметры, но сразу ошибкаNPP_EXEC: "Run"
CD: F:\
Current directory: F:\
java project
Process started >>>
Enter seconds:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at testone.main(testone.java:4)
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================

Answer (score 3):

Вы не передаете аргумент - следовательно появляется исключение, поскольку массив args пуст. Передайте аргумент, либо запускайте программу из командной строки c каким то аргументом.

Хотя можно сделать и так

```
package sample;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m=0;
    int s=0;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers");
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        m = n%360/60;  
        s = n%360%60; 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(m + " test " + s + " text"); //вывод по формулам и
 }
}
```